# Javascript create dom element template vs insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html

What is more efficent between these 2 methods (if we use lots of html) or preferable (futureproof etc)?

```js
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap')

function htmlToElement(html) {
    var template = document.createElement('template');
    html = html.trim(); 
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return template.content.firstChild;
}

var s = '<div class="parent"><div class="child">foo</div></div>'

//method 1
var elem = htmlToElement(s);
wrap.append(elem)


//method 2
wrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', s);
var elem2 = wrap.lastChild
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are both future proof and standard compliant.

However: **Method 2 is faster.**

How do I know? I wrote a test. :)

There seems to be a bigger difference in Firefox than Chrome, though:

**Chrome**

> method1 took 316.69999998807907 ms for 100000 calls

> method2 took 223.69999998807907 ms for 100000 calls

**Firefox**

> method1 took 214 ms for 100000 calls

> method2 took 95 ms for 100000 calls

**Test code**

```
var wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap')

function htmlToElement(html) {
  var template = document.createElement('template');
  html = html.trim();
  template.innerHTML = html;
  return template.content.firstChild;
}

var s = '<div class="parent"><div class="child">foo</div></div>'

//method 1
function method1() {
  var elem = htmlToElement(s);
  wrap.append(elem)
}

//method 2
function method2() {
  wrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', s);
  var elem2 = wrap.lastChild
}

// test calling a function multiple times and measure time taken
function timer(func, numberOfCalls) {
  let t1 = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCalls; i++) {
    func();
  }
  let t2 = performance.now();
  return `${func.name} took ${t2 - t1} ms for ${numberOfCalls} calls`
}

wrap.innerHTML = '';
console.log(timer(method1, 100000));
wrap.innerHTML = '';
console.log(timer(method2, 100000));
```

Try it out yourself, maybe with longer chunks of html and in more browsers and see the difference in performance for your self.

Comment: How do think this compare to using a global `DOMParser`? Is it just the selecting og the stuff and moving it to it's final location that slows this down? Curious.

Comment: I don't know, I would guess that would be similar in speed to just adding all html to a string and the writing it at once with .innerHTML, something that is usually rather fast. But depends on your app if that is a viable solution - do you add all html at once or at many different occasions?

Comment: Interesting. DOMParser is not that great for this at all. https://jsperf.app/jifize (on my safari mac) The differences aren't huge, though Chrome took significantly longer somehow. Same difference though. (Note: I had to do the `innerHTML = ''`, or the amount of elements would crash my browser. The page _hung badly_ anyway)